# Lazy Load Images using Spring Boot & Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, lazy-loading

**TLDR: I store *images* on a server with their *location* as a string on the *DB*. How can I *lazy* load these images in a *Thymeleaf* HTML page if I have a lot of images? How I access my images: `<img th:src="@{${project.imagePath}}">`**

I understand lazy loading when it comes to something like: `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="...", cascade=...)`. If you have a Restaurant then you may want to lazy load Reviews. My question is a bit different.

I have a model `Project(id, name, description, imagePath, ...)` with a MySQL table associated with it. Images are stored in the local directory/server directory and the location of the image is stored on the Project table as a string. I then use `<img th:src="@{${project.imagePath}}">` in Thymeleaf to display the image in the browser.

These Projects are added as a `List<Project>` to the Model. `model.addAttribute("projects", projectRepository.findAll());` Then in Thymeleaf I loop over the `projects` object and display each `project`.

Basic HTML/Thymeleaf:

```
    <div th:each="project : ${projects}" class="col">
        <img th:src="@{${project.imagePath}}">  
        <h1 th:text="${project.name}"></h1>
        <p class="project-description-text" th:text="${project.description}"></p>                   
    </div>
```

If I have 500+ **projects** with their own corresponding **images** that will take a lot of time to load the page and the user won't see the first images on their screen let alone the ones they have to scroll for without waiting too long. I know separate the projects by pages, but is there a way to just load the images as the user scrolls down.

I've read about [loading="lazy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading). I could understand that may work if my  tag src was a link tag to another page, **but will *loading="lazy"* work with *server-side rendering* as the one Thymeleaf does and *the way I store my images*?** What could be a possible solution for my case?

Thank you! <3

Comment: server side rendering only applies to the HTML not the images. Those are still downloaded by the browser after is receives the HTML. But I would suggest to reconsider rendering a page with all your projects, instead use pages and render say 50 and include a search box to limit the ones you want to view.